# Desktop Bridge Application Launch & Localization Issues

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have a legacy win32 application which I tried converting using the DAC providing the .msi from the application installer and the application works as is post conversion. But I have few queries below.

1. I used the same Base Image as my OS version for the conversion. But the converted application isn't launching on RS1 and RS2 OS images. It throws below error.

"This application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application."

2. My legacy application Installer has both Setup.exe as well as .msi file in the installation package. The setup exe only has language selection feature. Based on the user selection particular .mst file is passed as parameter to msi and launched.

Now while converting my desktop app, should I generate multiple appx files by providing all language .mst filenames as parameters to the .msi while conversion?

How to handle the above scenario so that my converted app should launch in that particular language based on the OS?

Also while appx installation can App Installer show in that OS language? How to support that in this converted application scenario?

Answer (score 0):

1) Of the top of my head, maybe you're missing dependencies like some VC++ redist?

2) The conversion process will only capture the language used to install the application, i.e. the one you specify in the command line. It cannot detect and include all the languages, even if your MSTs are present.

From what I know the AppInstaller for appx/msix packages cannot display a language selection dialog, this is all handled by the OS, transparent for the end-users.

If you plan to build a package with resources for multiple languages you need to [use MakePri](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/e76961b2-3f1a-4877-985c-b440227c9e80/desktop-converteruwphow-to-use-multilanguage-in-windows-desktop-app-converted-from-desktop-app?forum=wpdevelop). Check the linked thread for an example.

Also, another great [example on using MakePri](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/02/21/an-easier-way-to-generate-the-packages-for-a-desktop-bridge-converted-app/).

Comment: How to get missing dependencies in this case? Can't we get the dependencies packaged inside the converted app during conversion process? 
But it is working on RS3 & RS4 images.. still you believe it is an issue of VC++ dependencies?

Comment: If all RS images are clean, than most likely this is not a dependencies problem. From what I have seen in the past, the DAC should automatically detect your dependencies.

Try using ProcMon to see more details around the error.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon